# Qualitative behavior of a potential based on physically acceptable wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

[image]

Given the behavior of a wavefunction, how should one gain an intuition about the qualitative behavior of the potential in the S.E for which this wavefunction is a physically acceptable solution?

Looking for hints!

Comment: Are you assuming that $\Psi$ is a stationary state of the potential ?

Answer (score 0):

From the time-independ shr$\ddot{o}$dinger equation:

$$
   V(x) - E = \frac{1}{\Psi(x)}\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\Psi(x)}{dx^2}.
$$